# I am trying to send email from cPanel using codeigniter but every time I get the error saying connection time out

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, cpanel

I have used the following code to send email.

```
    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      'smtp_user' => 'username',
      'smtp_pass' => 'password',
      'smtp_port' => 587,
      'crlf' => "\r\n",
      'newline' => "\r\n",
      'mailtype' => "html"
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($email);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
```

This code works fine in my localhost but every time I run this code from cPanel I get the error saying.

Errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection timed out)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1846

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1869

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 688

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/pinesof1/public_html/flyannapurna.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)
Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
Line Number: 542
```

Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Max Execution time to a larger number, and see if that works for you.

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 108000);
?>
```

OR

You could change you're php.ini file

Comment: yup I added smtp_timeout on my config array and I got not response from the server and hung up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's not working on your code, but sure, there's a most simple solution that should work everytime, i use it:

```
$to = "yourTarget@someDomain.com";
$subject = "Your subject";
$message = "<html><body>Your message</body></html>";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n"
    ."From: theMailYouWantToUse@domain.com" ."\r\n"
    ."Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" ."\r\n"
    ."Reply: reply@yourDomain.com" ."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" .phpversion();

$mail_success = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

**Note**: you need all this headers or the mail is gonna go to junk.

### Bonus

I think it's better have a file with your message, and you often have some content to modify. Just use the code bellow before sending:

```
$message = file_get_contents("file.html");
$message = str_replace("%param1%",$param1,$message);
$message = str_replace("%param2%",$param2,$message);
```

Comment: If he wants to send emails using specific smtp server your code won't help.

Comment: yeah not helping. I need the solution that will send email from cPanel

Answer (score 0):

Very first error `Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection timed out)` says a lot about your problem. It means the port 587 is not accessible for you. It may happen by several reasons:

- This port is blocked on your server.
- Server's IP is blocked on smtp.sendgrid.net (probably your server is in blacklist)
- Network problems on your server

As far as I see 587 port is open for me on smtp.sendgrid.net as well as 25 port. Try 25 port also and see if you have the same issue. If you still see this error, ask your hosting company or your system administrator to check servers firewall for 587 port. You can also try to `telnet <DOMAIN_NAME> <PORT_NUMBER>` to see if you can connect to specific port from your server, this may help a lot to find the answer why this error occurs.

Comment: I tried port 25 and I got the same error. I tried telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587 and I got the error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587:25 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689